# Toggle Currency Format in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Basically I am attempting to do is allow the user to choose to show dollar formatting or not. Easy enough, just use `ng-class` to toggle the class, right? Except that now in empty cells a dollar sign shows.

What about if we use a custom filter? Well, I don't really know a way to toggle the custom filter on or off.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Here is the button that toggles the formatting (it runs a function that sets format to true or false).

```
<button class="btn format-toggle" ng-click="setFormat();">Show <span ng-show="format">Hours</span><span ng-hide="format">Dollars</span></button>
```

The code that I'm trying to affect

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="project in projects">
    <td>{{project.name}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="month in project.months" ng-class="{dollar : format}">{{month.total}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually answered my own question but I suppose I'll leave it up in case someone else finds it useful.

I ended up just using `ng-class` along with another condition to check that there was a value in the cell.

```
<td ng-repeat="month in project.months" ng-class="{dollar : format && month !== undefined}">{{month.total}}</td>
```

CSS:

```
.dollar:before{
  content:'$';
}
```